# Sudden "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

I have a java application that has been working fine until recently.
It started raising the exception:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I have a few versions of this application. For compilation and running: some are using the Java 8 that's on my path, some are using a specific reference to a Java 11 I have and some use an embedded Red Hat Java 11... Each uses a copy of the PKCS12 keystore. So, let's assume this file isn't corrupted.

- All suddenly stopped working with the above exception!
- To make matters more frustrating, simulating the failing API calls on the same machine, using Postman is passing just fine!
- If it matters, the java applications use a PKCS12 keystore, which was generated by keytool from crt+key files (which are the ones Postman is using)

Any ideas what's going on? I did have a Java update lined up, I updated (1.8.0_261 now) and restarted - still the same problem...

Update: Admin shared with me the old and new server certificates (not sure they are allowed to do that?). I was able to see some minor changes. Especially interesting looks the issuer:
Old: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, DigiCert Inc
New: DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1, DigiCert Inc
I guess it's a case of new issuer not trusted by Java? And I could potentially fix this by editing my cacerts file?
Would love a little light shed on this. So, I have some feeling of understanding, please :)

Comment: Please add details of both your certificate and the issuer's certificate: issuer, valid after, valid before.

Comment: I'd rather guess that your issuer's certificate was replaced in newer java, while Postman still keeps it. So, you'd better setup your app to serve certificate chain - not only the server certificate, but the issuer's certificate as well

Comment: I thought you didn't understand :D but actually, it looks like you are very close! Update in edit

Comment: please note that my application is a client. The issuer changed on the server certificate.

Comment: In my case, it occurs when sending an API request to remote service. It turned out that the remote service was not providing intermediate CA(DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1, DigiCert Inc) in certificate chain during SSL handshake. I reported this issue to the service and meanwhile, added intermediate CA to my Java cacerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, download the new intermediate certificate from [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm) in [PEM](http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertTLSRSASHA2562020CA1.crt.pem) or [DER](http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertTLSRSASHA2562020CA1.crt) format and import it to the CA store as trusted CA.

After that the case should get fixed.