Java HTTPS client abruptly lost ability to communicate with server using Let’s Encrypt
I have a server and client written in Java that uses Let’s Encrypt for TLS/SSL certs.
Everything was working great until July 7th 2024 when it stopped working after Let’s Encrypt issued new certs. The client would get the following error message:

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am assuming the problem is caused by Let’s Encrypt updating their chain of trust because the dates match perfectly. As a test I reverted to an older cert from Let’s Encrypt before the change and it still works, at least until it expires in the not too distant future.
Based on other posts on Stack Overflow, the most likely cause is that I do not have the most up to date intermediate CAs. However, following suggestions from others we have not been able to get it to work.

Update to from Java 17 to Java 22
Download intermediate certs from here: X1, R10 as pem files.

Manually add them to the JRE
Manually load them in the client


Obtained cert from relevant URL

Loading a website that uses the same Let’s Encrypt certs with Chrome works just fine. I verified that Java 22 had the latest certs that match what was on Let’s Encrypt website.
Here’s how I made sure the JRE had the correct certs. Using Chrome I verified the fingerprints that I needed were:
9D7C3F1AA6AD2B2EC0D5CF1E246F8D9AE6CBC9FD0755AD37BB974B1F2FB603F3
34C44664C5257A38FFAFAC3A2130138FFE22CE972F3660C788FDA87FA0B670F3
96BCEC06264976F37460779ACF28C5A7CFE8A3C0AAE11A8FFCEE05C0BDDF08C6
Relevant Certs within the keystore:
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit:

letsencrypt_r10, Jul 25, 2024, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 9D:7C:3F:1A:A6:AD:2B:2E:C0:D5:CF:1E:24:6F:8D:9A:E6:CB:C9:FD:07:55:AD:37:BB:97:4B:1F:2F:B6:03:F3

letsencryptisrgx1 [jdk], Jul 25, 2024, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 96:BC:EC:06:26:49:76:F3:74:60:77:9A:CF:28:C5:A7:CF:E8:A3:C0:AA:E1:1A:8F:FC:EE:05:C0:BD:DF:08:C6

webpage-cert, Jul 25, 2024, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 34:C4:46:64:C5:25:7A:38:FF:AF:AC:3A:21:30:13:8F:FE:22:CE:97:2F:36:60:C7:88:FD:A8:7F:A0:B6:70:F3

Other Relevant Links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977604/sudden-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target

I have also ran a test here: https://check-your-website.server-daten.de
With this I see that the certs are in good condition but the chain is incomplete. Looking on chrome again, although we get a 404 error it seems like we can connect and view the certs as well. I also tried connecting with a simple python script and it had the same problem as our java client.
Resolution found:
I was able to resolve this issue after dumping the contents of the PKCS12 and the converted (from PKCS12) JKS key. For some reason the JKS excluded the root certificate during conversion so it had to be manually added to the JKS.
The process:

Build a PKCS12 file out of the Let's Encrypt Fullchain and Privkey:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem -inkey /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem -out combined_keys.p12 -name $DOMAIN -passout pass:changeit


Convert the PKCS12 file to a JKS file:

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore $DOMAIN.jks -srckeystore combined_keys.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias $DOMAIN


Check with keytool -list -v -keystore $DOMAIN.jks -storepass changeit to see if a cert was missing.

Read the Fullchain and split the file into smaller files containing each individual certificate:


sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem | awk 'split_after == 1 {n++;split_after=0} /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1} {print > "/tmp/cert" n ".pem"}'


List the split files: ls /tmp/cert*.pem

Identify which  is which by listing the contents: openssl x509 -in /tmp/FILE_NAME.pem -text -noout

Import the missing cert:


sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file /tmp/FILE_NAME.pem -keystore $DOMAIN.jks -storepass changeit


Use a command line tool such as openssl s_client -connect <host>:443 to read what's coming from the server to ensure that it's actually supplying you with an up-to-date cert from the server that matches the expected cert chain. The error is likely at the server side, rather than at the client side.

@AnyaS+ add -showcerts to see the certs actually sent by the server; othierwise it shows only the EE cert in PEM plus the callback trace -- which some people think is relevant, but the callback trace is the chain rebuilt for validation not as received. OP: or if you don't have openssl but do have Java keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port]. Also check if the client (code or config) is specifying a nondefault truststore.

@dave_thompson_085 I'm getting 'Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)', however I don't think that's an issue. I ran the same command on another server that uses the older, but still working, Let's Encrypt cert and got the same error. I can post the entire dump if that's useful.

Updated main post with additional info gathered using https://check-your-website.server-daten.de

Okay, "incomplete chain" explains why Chrome works (it can 'fix' a missing chain using AIA) and python not (it doesn't) but since you've (very nonstandardly) added the EE cert to Java's default truststore your Java app should work IF it uses the default but not otherwise. So what does the Java app do?

I have added the solution which I found. It turns out the JKS conversion was dropping the root cert for whatever reason. I am currently looking into why this might be.
